# Check, uncheck items of checkbox in an array angularjs javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have an array named **namesData** that I am showing on the UI.
By default the checkboxes should be checked. When a checkbox is unchecked, that item should get removed from namesData. 
If the checkbox is checked, it should get added back to namesData.

```
$scope.namesData = [{"name":"abc.txt"}, {"name":"xyz.txt"}]
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="namesList in namesData">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="nameItem[$index].checked" ng-change="nameChange(namesList, nameItem[$index].checked, 'nameObj'+ $index, $index)" ng-checked="nameItem.checked" name="nameObj" id="{{'nameObj'+$index}}"/>&nbsp;
        <span>{{namesList.name}}</span>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.namesData = [{"name":"abc.txt"}, {"name":"xyz.txt"}];
$scope.nameItem.checked = true;

$scope.nameChange = function(list, isChecked, id, itemNum){
    if (isChecked){
        $scope.namesData.push(list);
    }
    else
        $scope.namesData.splice($scope.newNamesList.indexOf(list), 1);
};
```

**Issue:** The problem with the above logic is that the checked/unchecked items are getting added/removed to the end of the namesData array rather than its actual index item.
Please advise how to resolve this.

Comment: code to remove looks fine. Add may have issues. Are you certain that remove also removes the last element instead of the one specified in the index?

Comment: If I am checking/unchecking abc.txt, the logic is pushing/removing abc.txt again in namesData rather than working with abc.txt that is already there in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to submit only the checked items, how about using a logic similar to below one. You filter the checked items from your array and work with them. If you really need to modify the original array you have to keep a copy of the original array and insert checked items to its position by checking the original array.

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.namesData = [{
    name: "abc.txt",
    checked: true
  }, {
    name: "xyz.txt",
    checked: true
  }];
  $scope.nameItem = {
    checked: true
  };


  $scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.selectedList = $scope.namesData.filter(function(namesDataItem) {
      return namesDataItem.checked;
    });
    console.log($scope.selectedList);
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="namesList in namesData">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="namesList.checked" />&nbsp;
    <span>{{namesList.name}}</span>
  </div>
  <button ng-click=submit()>Submit</button>
  <div ng-repeat="selected in selectedList">
    {{selected.name}}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks cubbuk. This solution works if we want to use a different array to store the checked values.